# Direct Access on Server 2012

Tags: domain-controller, windows-server-2012, direct-access

**Scenario**: Windows Server 2012 with the Remote Access role installed.  IP set to static, registered DNS.  3 domain controllers, all running Server 2003 (*I suspect this may be the issue*)

**Done so far:** DNS registered, firewall turned off after IPsec was applied. Able to ping all 3 DC's with no issues

**Problem:**
Going through the DA wizard generates this error.  I am logged in as a domain admin, verified that I can ping the DC, verified IPsec allows me to contact it.  Since this version hasnt been readily deployed yet, there isnt much help available online from what I can find.

[image: error]

Any assistance ayone could provide would be greatly appreciated.  I am still new to the server world as far as things are considered.  I would fit, user wise, between Superuser.com and serverfault.com (junior admin)

Thanks to anyone who may be able to assist!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DirectAccess requires at least one Server 2008 or above Active Directory DC with IPv6 enabled.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee382305(v=ws.10).aspx for all requirements.

Keep in mind, without a 6to4 NAT Device (Forefront UAG, etc...), DirectAccess only allows access to IPv6 resources.  2003 and XP have limited IPv6 support, and require extra configuration to get working.

Comment: Thanks.  Thats what I figured, but apparently I need more coffee.  Going to put this on our "Why we should upgrade" whiteboard